# Bibliography with biblatex: how to create additional labels using authoryear-style?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, labels

I've got a problem with my bibliography. I'm working with `biblatex` using authoryear-style. I did some modifications for my semester paper, but there's still one problem left: I'd like to display **additionally** the last name(s) of the author and the year in the bibliography (just as in the continuous text). Both last name and year should be formatted bold. Here's an example:

In the continuous text: Test (Bögelsack et al. 1985).

In the bibliography:

**Bögelsack et al. 1985**

Bögelsack, G.; Kallenbach, E.; Linnemann, G. (1985): Roboter in der Gerätetechnik.
Heidelberg: A. Hüthig. isbn: 3778510428.

Here's my .tex:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, maxcitenames=2, firstinits=true, uniquename=init, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\addbibresource{Label.bib}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareNameFormat{sortname}{
\iffirstinits
    {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}%
    \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\ al\adddot}}

\begin{filecontents}{Label.bib}
@book{Bogelsack.1985,
author = {B{\"o}gelsack, G. and Kallenbach, Eberhard and Linnemann, Gerhard},
year = {1985},
title = {Roboter in der Ger{\"a}tetechnik},
address = {Heidelberg},
publisher = {A. H{\"u}thig},
isbn = {3778510428}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Test (\cite{Bogelsack.1985}).

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I spent many hours searching on the web to find a solution, but I didn't find anything about this topic. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Hi Guido, Thank you very much for your rapid response! That's exactly what I wanted!!! Best regards, Tom

Comment: Now I've got a further question. Is it possible to display "a, b, c" after the lableyear (in case that I've got the same author and the same lableyear more than once)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you, Guido! Is it possible to set a counter like "maxbibnames=2" in the begentry-macro? Something like "maxlabelnames=2"? At the moment it displays "Warnecke et al." for a book with two authors. I want to display "Warnecke & Williams". Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To achieve the desired result the simplest way is to redefine the `begentry` hook to print the `labelname` and `labelyear`.

```
\renewbibmacro{begentry}{%
\textbf{\printnames[][-\value{liststop}]{labelname}~\printfield{labelyear}\printfield{extrayear}}\\}
```

[image]

**EDIT** inserted `\printfield{extrayear}` to handle the case of multiple labels with the same combination of author-year.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was asked `biblatex-ext` has been released. The styles of that bundle offer a built-in solution for this question with the `introcite` option. You can read more about this option in [§4.2. *Style-specific options* of the `biblatex-ext` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf).

With `introcite=plain` and two small redefinitions we should be there.

The code in the MWE has been modernised to make use of newer `biblatex` features.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear,
  introcite=plain,
  maxcitenames=2, giveninits=true, uniquename=init,]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\introcitepunct}{\newline}
\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbold{#1}}


\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias*[bib]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitldelim}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1\isdot}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\ al\adddot}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Test \autocite{sigfridsson}.

Test \autocite{companion}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography entries with citation 'heading'/label in bold]