# Customize biblatex citations

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm exploring the capabilities of biblatex. I'm using the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,natbib=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text about \citet{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This results in the following output:

[image: current output]

Instead, I'd like to format citations as `[Author(2001)]` instead of `[Auth2001]`, as illustrated below.

[image: desired result]

How can I achieve this customized citation? Ideally, I'd like to keep the available natbib commands (currently achieved through `natbib=true`) and modify my current invocations of `\cite` as little as possible.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68875/5872

Comment: Maybe you could just use an `authoryear` style and some modification like in [Adding an AuthorYear block at the beginning of bibliography entries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11827/35864), [Bibliography with biblatex: how to create additional labels using authoryear-style?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139860/35864) or [Modifying alphabetic biblabels with biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155812/35864)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by henrique above hinted me at the correct solution. Switching to biber and using `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate` solves the problem. Note that for the case of multiple authors, `maxalphanames=1` limits the number of authors that are listed in a citation to 1 and `\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}` omits the `+` that would appear in entries for multiple authors otherwise.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,natbib=true,backend=biber,maxalphanames=1]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A. and Bernard, B.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{labelname}
    \field{label}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \literal{(}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field{year}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \literal{)}
  }
}

\begin{document}

Some text about \citet{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```